# Distributed image processing on AWS: how to know the address of master node?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, scaling, distributed-computing

Context: I am building a mobile application that will let users apply advanced filters to their pictures. Since the processing can't be done on the phone, it will be offloaded to EC2 instances.

I plan on having one "master" node which will receive the HTTP requests, check authentication, and add them to a redis queue.

Then I will have multiple GPU-enable "processing" nodes that will ask the master for work, and report back when the processing is done. The processing nodes will be switched on and off depending on the request queue size.

**How should the processing nodes know the address of the master node?**

Is there any built-in solution from AWS? Can I assume the master's IP will be static and simply provide the processing node with it at startup? Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a DNS record for your master node, which your slaves can look up when needed.

If your master changes IPs periodically, have it use the Route53 API to update its own record when needed.